# How to use Manipulate to show linear transformation of matrix?

Tags: matrix, manipulate

I've seen GIFs like this in a China websit. It shows how a matrix works on a Cartesian coordinates. I wanna make my own one to show to my students.

[image: Copyright reserved by the original author of the GIF]

This GIF shows the effect of the matrix A={{1,-2},{1.5,0.5}}. I contact with the original author, only to get words "This is made with Wolfram. Thank you."

After I read the reference of Mathematica, I know Manipulate can do it. But how? I mean, how to draw the gird of Cartesian coordinates and use a matrix to WORK on the gird.

Thanks for reading my question and helping me solve it.

Comment: some of us can't read the Chinese language. Can you explain what the slider does? But have you searched the Wolfram demo site? There are many such demos there already with source code. I am sure you'll find one similar to it. http://demonstrations.wolfram.com/search.html?query=transformation

Comment: @Nasser Well, I think that the Chinese on the GIF doesn't matter. It's just the progress of animation. In math, you put the matrix to the coordinates, and then, booooom, you get the result, no intermediate. And, if you real don't understand, you can see this video [link](https://youtu.be/kYB8IZa5AuE?list=PLZHQObOWTQDPD3MizzM2xVFitgF8hE_ab) which show the same topic.

Comment: @Nasser `origin={{1, 0}, {0, 1}};A={{1, -2}, {1.5, 0.5}};progress = origin + k*A` The slider controls the value of k, from 0 to 1. `progress`is the matrix below the right part. In fact the right part shows the matrix `progress`, not the matrix `A`.

Comment: Sorry, `origin={{1, 0}, {0, 1}};A={{1, -2}, {1.5, 0.5}};progress = origin + k*(A - origin)`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

An interesting question anyway, so let me give an answer. Please read the document carefully to understand it.

```
outer = Outer[#, Range[-3, 3], {-3, 3}] &;
arrow = Arrow[{{0, 0}, #}] &;
vector = Overscript[#, "⇀"] &;
grid = {Text[vector@"j", {-0.2, 0.5}], Text[vector@"i", {0.5, -0.2}], Gray, 
   Line[outer[{#, #2} &]~Join~outer[{#2, #} &]], ColorData[1][1], Arrowheads[.03], 
   arrow@{0, 1}, ColorData[1][2], arrow@{1, 0}};
origin = {{1, 0}, {0, 1}};
mat = {{1, -2}, {1.5, 0.5}};
rotate[k_] = GeometricTransformation[grid, origin + k (mat - origin)];
Manipulate[
 Show[Graphics[{grid, rotate@k}], PlotRange -> 3], {k, 0, 1}]
```

[image]

Comment: Amazing. And there are many grammars that I'm not familiar with. I need to learn. :-) However, how can I change the color of the gird? I've tried `{Style[grid, Red]` but nothing happened.

Comment: @kane Please check the document of `Graphics` carefully.

Comment: Upvote,and I will suggest to use `Opacity[.3, Gray]` but not `Gray` directly. :)

Comment: if you want to see matrix: Manipulate[
 Show[Graphics[{grid, rotate@k}], PlotRange -> 3], {k, 0, 1}, 
 Dynamic[MatrixForm[origin + k (mat - origin)]]]

Answer (score 2):

```
n = 3;
vertices = Union[#, Reverse[#, 2]] &[Tuples[{{-n, n}, Range[-n, n]}]];
lines = Flatten[Lookup[PositionIndex[vertices], #]] &[Flatten[{
           GatherBy[SortBy[vertices, Last], First][[All, {1, -1}]],
           GatherBy[SortBy[vertices, First], Last][[All, {1, -1}]]}, 2]];

ini = Graphics[{Black, Line /@ Partition[vertices[[lines]], 2]}, 
        AspectRatio -> Automatic, PlotRange -> 2 {{-n, n}, {-n, n}}]

Manipulate[Show[ini, Graphics[Line /@ Partition[#[[lines]], 2]]] &[
 vertices.((1 - t) {{1, 0}, {0, 1}} + Transpose[{{1, -2}, {1.5`, 0.5`}}] t)], {t, 0, 1}]
```

[image]

Comment: Excuse me. How can I change the color of the original gird? I mean the first one of `[ini, Graphics[Line /@...`, and keep the later one unchanged.

Comment: @KaneGreen I added a color in the definition of `ini`